# How can I extract data from multiple webpage using one import.io connector?

Tags: import.io

I need to extract data from multiple pages on a website. Can I do it with one connector or I have to create multiple connector to get data and group them later ? As an example i am trying to collect data for stocks but it is spread on multiple pages.

Here are the diffrent pages I am trying to collect the information - 
http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/powergenerationdistribution/suzlonenergy/SE17

http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/suzlonenergy/balance-sheet/SE17#SE17

http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/suzlonenergy/ratios/SE17#SE17

How do I write one extractor to fetch data from these different pages ?

Answer (score 1):

If the URLs of the pages are different then it would be best to use an extractor and paste the URLs into it, this way you can get live data at the click of a button. It would be really cool to get a few of the URLs so we can take a look at them.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alex, I have updated the question with URLs. I did not understand when you said "paste the URLs into it". can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Hi Amit. During the workflow, it gives you the option to add another page. When you click on this button, you can enter a new URL into the URL bar.